# How do I go about evaluating the Lebesgue integral on $[1, \infty)$ of $f:[1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=(-1)^n/n$ on $[n, n+1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to solve the following problem from section 4.5 in Royden's Real Analysis:

> For each of the two functions $f$ on $[1, \infty)$ defined below, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_1^n f$ exists while $f$ is not integrable over $[1,\infty)$. Does this contradict the continuity of integration?
> (i) Define $f(x) = (-1)^n/n$, for $n\leqslant x < n+1$.

I can see that $f$ is a simple function on the interval $[1, n)$ so we have $$\int_{[1, n)} f = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{[k, k+1)} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}.$$
We then have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[1, n)} f = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}.$$
The limit exists by the alternating series test.

However, I don't understand how can I show that $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[1, \infty)$. I am trying to show equivalently that $|f|$ is not lebesgue integrable. Trouble is, I can't think of how to evaluate this integral $$\int_{[1, \infty)} |f|.$$

Edit: Can we reason as follows: Let $f_n$ be the following increasing sequence of non-negative measurable function on $[1, \infty)$:

$$f_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \chi_{[k, k+1)}.$$ Then $\{f_{n}\} \to  |f|$ pointwise a.e. on $[1,\infty)$ (I'm not sure if I can justify this). We then have from the monotone convergence theorem
\begin{align*}
 \int_{[1,\infty)} |f| &= \lim_{n \to  \infty} \int_{[1, \infty)} f_{n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[1,\infty)}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}\cdot \chi_{[k, k+1)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[1,n)} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \cdot \chi_{[k, k+1)} \quad \text{(because integrand is nonzero on $[1, n)$)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} = \infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: Your last integral only makes sense with n interpreted as a real variable. However I don't think that's what you want. In fact you cannot say $|f|=1/n,$ since the n depends on which length 1 subinterval of $[1. \infty)$ is being considered.

Comment: Note that $|f|$ does NOT equal one fixed $1/n$ everywhere, it is $1/n$ on $[n,n+1)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll edit my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\int_{[1, n)} |f| = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{[k, k+1)} \frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \infty$$
we have $f \notin L^1([1,\infty))$. Thus, $f$ is not (Lebesgue) integrable.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering. However, this isn't probably the method the author intended to be used to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the author's intention, then? Anyway, I believe this is how integrable functions are defined. I'm just using the definition! @JohnSmith

Comment: I meant he probably intends for the theorems proven so far in the text to be used to solve the problem. $L^{1}$ spaces aren't defined yet either. Maybe you are using the definition but I couldn't follow your reasoning (or lack thereof).

Comment: What do you understand by "integrable"? @JohnSmith

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
\int_1^n f(x)\ \mathsf dx = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(-1)^i}i \stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow -\log 2
$$
(as observed from the series expansion of $x\mapsto\log(1-x)$ at $x=-1$), so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_1^n f(x)\ \mathsf dx$ exists, but clearly $$\int_1^\infty |f(x)|\ \mathsf dx = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1i=+\infty, $$ so that $f$ is not integrable over $[1,\infty)$. This does not condradict the continuity of integration (Theorem 21 in the text), as integrability of $f$ was an assumption for the result to hold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you comment on what I wrote as an answer? In particular, is what I wrote about the pointwise convergence of the sequence to $|f|$ right?